# Dynamic json chart

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I'm trying to use Sencha Touch Charts with a JSONStore to dynamically display a chart from information provided by JSON, series and data. This was possible with ExtJS 3 with the metaData property.

How can I accomplish the same with Sencha Touch Charts?

Answer (score 0):

```
//    Am using ruby for the webservice calls.

// First u have to create model and store for that



// model 
 Ext.regModel('samplemodel', {
idProperty: 'name',
fields: [ { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
              { name: 'data', type: 'int' }
            ]
});

// store
Ext.regStore('SampleStore', {
model: 'samplemodel',
storeId: "sampleStoreID",
sorters: [ {
    property: 'name'
}]
});

// and create a variable for the store 

var sampleStore = Ext.getStore("SampleStore");

// call the webservice and store it in array,
// bind the response to the store,
// use the store variable in the chart.
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161912-Dynamic-json-chart